# Using two jquery functions on the same page issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having some issues where my page contains two jquery function on the same page, while one of the function loads the other doesn't.

I am a novice to Jquery so will try to explain carefully what is going on and appreciate if anyone can help with some basic advice.

Basically I copied from the net 2 jquery functions that have never been put together, I just want the both features to work on the same page.

In the head section of my page. I am using:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

which the below function in the body tag uses:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  $(function() { 
   $('#container').nested(); 
    });
</script>
```

then below the body tag I am calling:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which below function is using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    // start jqtweet!
    JQTWEET.loadTweets();
}); 
</script>
```

Seperately both these functions work, but not together. It's frustrating and I may have broken some rules hence why it isn't working.

Comment: You only need to include jQuery the once.

Comment: Im not sure if this will work so Im not putting it as an answer yet. You're loading in the jQuery library twice: it's the line where you have (...)src="//ajax.(..). Don't load that again after you did it once at the top of your page.

Secondly, the $(function() { part will evaluate everything in it when the page loads. I'd put both if your codes in one of those encapsulations instead of the two.

Comment: try to use `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: When you include jQuery second time the `$` jQuery is overwritten and you lose everything

Comment: @maurycy If this is true then that is the answer, I didn't know it but it sounds sensable. If jQuery is overwritten then all registered events (i.e. $(document).ready()) is lost.

Comment: @Glubus it won't be completely lost, the event would be attached and exist but it will lost a reference to the callback and it would not work

Comment: I have removed the jquery 1.10.2 from the head section and there has been no difference. Then if I move the jquery 1.8.2 to the head section the JQTWEET function doesn't load.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to load the `JQuery` twice. Also, put the two fuctions together:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').nested(); 
    // start jqtweet!
    JQTWEET.loadTweets();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: And also, just use the most recent version of jquery (1.10.2).  Loading two different versions probably wasn't helpful.

Comment: Merging the two together doesn't seem to work for some reason, not sure if it has anything to do with the fact that one function is placed in the body and the other below the body tag.  So combining the two functions I have tried putting in the body and below the body and neither has worked.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxWXWv here is the page that pulls everything in, may not help as there are a few external sources. Thanks in advanced, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting them in a single script inside a document ready function?

Like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#container').nested();
    JQTWEET.loadTweets();
});
```